# How to stay on the UserFrom during the excution of the vba

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a Button in the UserForm where I have coded to do some specific task.  The Issue is as soon as I press the button the window will switch itself to the specified workbook in the code do the assigned work and comeback to the UserForm once the execution is finished.
I want the Userform to stay on the screen from start till the end of the execution instead of switching over.
Here is the Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Dim hyperlink As String
 Dim wbAcro As Workbook
 Dim WsEPC As Worksheet


 Set wbEPC = Workbooks("" & EPC_Datasheet): wbEPC.Activate

 Set WsEPC = wbEPC.Worksheets("Sheet1")

 Set wbAcro = Workbooks.Open("C:\EPC AutoTool\Acronyms\Acronyms Details.xlsx")


    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
  Dim LstRw As Long, rng As Range, C As Range, Frng As Range, Frng2 As Range
  Dim LstR_Template As Integer
  Set sh = wbAcro.Sheets("Sheet1")
  Set ws = wbEPC.Sheets("Sheet1")




 With sh

      .Activate
    LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = .Range("B2:B" & LstRw)

End With


 With ws
    .Activate
    .Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    LstR_Template = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    '*****************
    Dim num As String
    Dim cf As Range

    With .Range("B1:B" & LstR_Template)

     Set cf = .Find(what:=Unique_ID, _
    lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)



    num = cf.Address
    Range(num).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    .Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy
    Range(num).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Select
    .Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).PasteSpecial

    End With
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change the Showmodal property of your form and see the impact.

Comment: Catalin is right. when you show your form, add vbModeless to the end of it. I.e. UserForm1.Show vbModeless. This will keep your form as the focus.

Comment: @Catalin Pop and DDuffy  - I changed the ShowModal Property to False in the Userform Properties, but still the UserForm is not being focused, instead I can see all the operations which is happening in the Workbook.